# Authentication using JQuery SignalR library

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, signalr

I have a server hub which needs to know the identity of the calling user, in order to return the correct data. Previously the system used REST and using the REST HTTP headers, it extracted the windows credentials.

However now I am just using pure SignalR calls, eg on connect it returns you all of your data. However without knowing who you are, it cannot return YOUR data.

I've been looking around for a way to pass windows credentials via jquery signalr but cannot see anything. Is this even possible? Surely there must be a way to authenticate with jquery signalr?

My signalr connection initialisation

```
const url: string = hostlookup().host + `/MyService/signalr`;
const connection = $.hubConnection(url, {
     useDefaultPath: false     
}) as any;

connection.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the
[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization)

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connection = new HubConnection("http://www.contoso.com/");
        connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        connection.Start().Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's C#, not javascript. My client is pure javascript